# Java Regex Match Not Matching Set of OR'd Words, Remaining Work Fine

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to write a regex to tokenize the following strings,

```
turn on 931,331 through 939,812
turn off 756,53 through 923,339
toggle 756,965 through 812,992
```

Here's my regex,

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[(turn on)|(turn off)|(toggle)] (\\d+),(\\d+) through (\\d+),(\\d+)");


for (String word : lines) {
        Matcher m = pattern.matcher(word);
        if (m.find()) {
            System.out.println(m.group(0));
        }
    }
```

Returns the following result,

```
n 931,331 through 939,812
f 756,53 through 923,339
e 756,965 through 812,992
```

My regex groups 1 to 4 return the 4 numbers i'm matching against but for some reason I can't capture the strings "turn on" or "turn off" or "toggle" into group 1, followed by having the numbers in their own group?

If I use the following regex,

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(turn on) (\\d+),(\\d+) through (\\d+),(\\d+)");
```

I can capture "turn on" in group 1 and then each digit in its own group. But then I'd have to build another Pattern obj for "turn off" and "toggle"

What am I getting wrong?

I've also tried this variation,

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([turn on|turn off|toggle]) (\\d+),(\\d+) through (\\d+),(\\d+)");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use a [character set](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) to group the capturing groups (which will match one character between the brackets), which is why only one character is being matched in your case.

*If* you want to group the capturing groups, you could use a non-capturing group instead:

```
(?:(turn on)|(turn off)|(toggle)) (\\d+),(\\d+) through (\\d+),(\\d+)
```

But that's not necessary, since you can just use the following:

```
(turn on|turn off|toggle) (\\d+),(\\d+) through (\\d+),(\\d+)
```